# Regarding the number of partial orders $P_n$ on an $n$-set

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, order-theory

Regarding the set of partial orders $P_n$ on an $n$-set, it is known that $$|P_n|\geq {2^\frac{n^2}{4}}$$ If I replace $n$ by $2n$, I get $$|P_{2n}|\geq 2^{n^2}$$
So, if a $2n$-set, say $A=\{1,2,3,\cdots,2n\}$ is partitioned into two sets $A_1=\{1,2,3,\cdots,n\}$ and $A_2=\{n+1,n+2,n+3,\cdots,2n\}$, then doesn't it mean there there exists a function $$f:\mathcal{P}(A_1\times A_1)\to P_{2n}$$ such that $f$ is one-one, $\mathcal{P(A)}$ being the symbol for power set  of $\mathcal{A}$? If yes, how would that function $f$ be constructed?

Comment: Well, a subset of $S\subseteq A_1\times A_2$ almost a partial order. If $A=A_1\cup A_2$ we define, for $a,b\in A$ that $a\leq_S b$ if $a= b$ or $a\in A_1,b\in A_2,$ and $(a,b)\in S.$

Comment: Let, for example, $A=\{1,2,3,4\}, A_1=\{1,2\}, A_2=\{3,4\}$. For $S=\{(1,3),(2,3)\}$, you suggest $\leq_S =\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(1,3)(2,3)\}$. Right?

Comment: Why did you write "almost", by the way?

Comment: Yes. That example is fine. It is only “almost” a partial order, as a set, because it doesn’t include the $a=b$ case. A partial order on $A$ can be seen as a subset of $A\times A$ with a number of properties, and $S$ is missing the diagonal elements, which is required for a partial order.

Comment: This shows what a crude lower bound this is: $2^{n^2}$ counts  only the subset orders of height $1$ or $2$ of the set of $2n$ elements.

Comment: Is there a known improvement of the lower bound $2^\frac{n^2}{4}$ for $P_n$?